# React App running on EC2 instance is Accessible through AWS public DNS for around 20 minutes then displays "Unable to connect" in Browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-connect

**Background**
I have a pretty simple react app created using npx create-react-app and an express server. I have it hosted on an EC2 instance that I set up according to this guide: https://sumantmishra.medium.com/how-to-deploy-node-js-app-on-aws-with-github-db99758294f1

I run my app by SSHing (through the AWS console) into the instance and then running 'npm run start:prod', after which my site is accessible via the public DNS from AWS (e.g. http://ec2-3-22-81-76.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/) and the app behaves correctly.

My 'start:prod' script is as follows:

"export NODE_ENV=production&& concurrently "nodemon --ignore 'client/*'" "npm run client""

**Issue**
But after around 20 minutes, though, if I load the page again the app/server is no longer accessible and displays the following:
[image]

And this is what is displayed in the network tab:
[image]

The inaccessibility of the server occurs whether I've been using the app, or, just pulled it up and let it sit. It's as if the actual functioning of the application isn't coming into play, but rather that it's something at the infrastructure level.

I have checked that the public IP and DNS for the EC2 instance are not changing within this time, and are the same as when they were when the server and app were behaving correctly.

**EC2 instance Seurity Group**
I have seen similar issues in other threads where the issue was with the security group. I have not found an issue, however, in which the site is accessible and then becomes inaccessible after some amount of time.

The security group settings for my instance are as follows:
[image]

I have set a security rule to allow inbound TCP traffic on port 3000 (which is the port my express server is running on), which I think would allow access indefinitely, but something is going wrong causing the site to become inaccessible.

Any ideas about what the issue might be?

Comment: An idea - express process stopped or exited. Can you share the full command you start express? Is it just as `npm start`?

Comment: @VasylHerman Good suggestion. Will have to set up Express server logging and then check. I see that the morgan dependency can perform logging. And I am actually starting my app with 'npm run start:prod'. Updated the question to show the script in full.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that the `npm run start:prod` process has stopped or exited at the moment when you see the issue. The reason is an SSH session lives approximately 20 mins and it kind of cleans started processes on SSH exit.

**Quick solution:** ssh to your server and run `nohup npm run start:prod > output.log 2>&1 &`

**Better solution:** use [forever](https://github.com/foreversd/forever), an example for a regular react app:

```
npm install forever -g
forever start  node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js start
```

**Best solution:** use CloudFront with S3 origins for static content. Or [dockerize](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp) your express server and start with `docker compose up -d`, set `restart: always` directive.

Comment: @DeanPortman, the *Quick solution* may not work well. I tested the *forever* package is works stable. Regardless of any, consider CloudFront with an S3 origin for SPA

Comment: You can also use the process manager to run your react application in background.https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/

Comment: Running 'nohup npm run start:prod > output.log 2>&1 &' once it becomes unavailable does indeed make it accessible again. Currently working on getting it containerized